# override method on python object. missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, inheritance, composition

I have a simple class:

```
class MyClass():
    
    ... 
    
    def function(self):
        return self.transform(**self.kwargs)
        
    def transform(self, **kw):
        ''' main '''
        return 1
```

I tried to override the `transform` method, but when it's called by the `function` method it fails.

```
def t(self, **kw):
    return 2

instance = MyClass()
instance.transform = t
instance.function()

> missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

weird right? I thought the `self.` denotes that it's passing the `self` in as the first argument automatically...?

So it works if I don't include self.

```
def t(**kw):
    return 2

instance = MyClass()
instance.transform = t
instance.function()

> 2
```

But that means my `t` function can't access any of the attributes of the object. Can you help me?

Of course I could create a new class that derives from MyClass, but I don't want to. Any other way to inject a method to an object that can access the objects memory?

Comment: Methods *belong to a class*. For a function to operate as a method, i.e. passing the instance as the first argument when called on an instance, then the function needs to belong to the class so that the descriptor protocol can do that (which is how that all works). What you are doing isn't overriding, and has nothing to do with inheritance, you are simply *shadowing* the method on the class with an instance attribute that happens to be a function. It's just a function at that point, the same as if it were in the global scope

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I appreciate the clarity but how do I make the method belong to the class?

Comment: To do something like this, you must manually partially apply the instance to the function object. See the linked duplicate. Something to the effect of `instance.transform = lambda **kw: t(self, **kw)` or `instance.transform = functools.partial(t, instance)`

Comment: Or, to replicate what function objects do in their descriptor protocol, `instance.transform = types.MethodType(t, instance)`

Comment: However, are you actually trying to do this at the *instance level*? If not, then just do `MyClass.transform = t`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the partial solution seems most intuitive to me, any reason to prefer one way of doing this over another, such as the one you indicated or monkey patching? `from functools import partial; instance.transform = partial(t, instance)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, at the instance level, I'm going to import MyClass once, build instances and change how that one function works in different ways on all of the objects. so monkey patching is probably not the best for that, but it could work.

Comment: Note that you can change an object's type retroactively, and generate a new class with an arbitrary set of superclasses. Mind, it's been way back in the day (pre-Python 3) since I ever actually _did_ anything that hacky...

Comment: Not sure exactly which one you are referring to as monkey-patching, `MyClass.transform = t`? That is different. That changes the method for *all instances of the class*. There might be implications with regards to the docstrings, etc for choosing `types.MethodType`, but they are all fundamentally the same solution, shadowing the class attribute with an instance attribute that partially applies the instance as the first argument to the function. I would just design the class to accept a transform as a dependency and do something like `return self.transform(self, *args, **kwargs)` in `function`